# I tried to divide resnet into two parts using pytorch children(), but it doesn't work

Tags: pytorch

Here is a simple example. I tried to divide a network (Resnet50) into two parts: `head` and `tail` using `children`. Conceptually, this should work but it doesn't. Why is it?

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torchvision.models import resnet50

head = nn.Sequential(*list(resnet.children())[:-2])
tail = nn.Sequential(*list(resnet.children())[-2:])
x = torch.zeros(1, 3, 160, 160)

resnet(x).shape      # torch.Size([1, 1000])
head(x).shape        # torch.Size([1, 2048, 5, 5])
tail(head(x)).shape  # Error: RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [2048 x 1], m2: [2048 x 1000] at /pytorch/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensorMath.cpp:136
```

For information, the tail is nothing but

```
Sequential(
  (0): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(1, 1))
  (1): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=1000, bias=True)
)
```

So I actually know that if I can do like this. But then, why the reshaping function (`view`) is not in the children?

```
pool =resnet._modules['avgpool']
fc = resnet._modules['fc']
fc(pool(head(x)).view(1, -1))
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking to do is separate the feature extractor from the classifier.

- What I should point out straight away, is that [*Resnet*](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/models/resnet.py) is not a sequential model (as the name implies - *residual network* - it as residuals)!

  Therefore compiling it down to a `nn.Sequential` will not be accurate. There's a difference between model definition the layers that appear ordered with `.children()` and the actual underlying implementation of that model's `forward` function.

- The flattening you performed using `view(1, -1)` is not registered as a layer in all `torchvision.models.resnet*` models. Instead it is performed on [this line](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/models/resnet.py#L243) in the `forward` definition:

  ```
  x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
  ```

  They could have registered it as a layer in the `__init__` as `self.flatten = nn.Flatten()`, to be used in the `forward` implementation as `x = self.flatten(x)`.

  Even so `fc(pool(head(x)).view(1, -1))` is completely different to `resnet(x)` (*cf.* first point).

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `nn.Flatten` module into `tail` seems to solve your problem:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torchvision.models import resnet50
resnet = resnet50()
head = nn.Sequential(*list(resnet.children())[:-2])
tail = nn.Sequential(*[list(resnet.children())[-2], nn.Flatten(start_dim=1), list(resnet.children())[-1]])
x = torch.zeros(1, 3, 160, 160)

resnet(x).shape      # torch.Size([1, 1000])
head(x).shape        # torch.Size([1, 2048, 5, 5])
tail(head(x)).shape  # torch.Size([1, 1000])
```